# C# Workflow ManualWorkflowSchedulerService Multithreading Question

Tags: c#, multithreading, workflow

Hey guys, I just wanted to verify what I'm doing is correct.  It came to our attention that a Windows Service had a pretty serious memory leak.  I was able to track it down to how Workflow was being called.  I reworked it a bit to stop the memory leak, but I wanted to validate that the code is doing what I think it is.  Note I do not know the first thing about Workflow, so I'm coming to you.

Basically, the code was executing the Workflow on a thread, but was not removing the handler to WorkflowRuntime.Terminated.  I am trying to ensure that the Workflow is executed asynchronously.  Here are the relevant portions of code:

Checking to ensure there is only once instance of the WorkflowRuntime:

```
private static void _CheckRuntimeInstance()
{
     lock (_padlock)
     {
          if (_wfRuntime == null)
          {
               _wfRuntime = new WorkflowRuntime();

               ManualWorkflowSchedulerService schedulerService = new ManualWorkflowSchedulerService();
                _wfRuntime.AddService(schedulerService);
                _wfRuntime.StartRuntime();                 
           }
      }
}
```

Inside a static method, creating the specific WorkflowInstance to run:

```
_CheckRuntimeInstance();

// create the instance
WorkflowInstance instance = _wfRuntime.CreateWorkflow(typeof(WorkflowType),parameters);
instance.Start();

Guid instanceId = instance.InstanceId;

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(CallbackMethod, instanceId);
```

Thread callback method:

```
private static void DeviceLocationAssignmentCallback(Object state)
{
     Guid instanceId = (Guid)state;

     EventHandler<WorkflowTerminatedEventArgs> workflowTerminatedHandler = null;
     EventHandler<WorkflowCompletedEventArgs> workflowCompletedHandler = null;

     workflowTerminatedHandler = delegate(object sender, WorkflowTerminatedEventArgs e)
     {
         if (instanceId == e.WorkflowInstance.InstanceId)
         {
             // Remove event registration.
             _wfRuntime.WorkflowTerminated -= workflowTerminatedHandler;
             _wfRuntime.WorkflowCompleted -= workflowCompletedHandler;

             if (e.Exception != null)
             {
                // Log error.
             }
         }
     };

     _wfRuntime.WorkflowTerminated += workflowTerminatedHandler;

     workflowCompletedHandler = delegate(object sender, WorkflowCompletedEventArgs e)
     {
         if (instanceId == e.WorkflowInstance.InstanceId)
         {
             // Remove event registrations.
             _wfRuntime.WorkflowTerminated -= workflowTerminatedHandler;
             _wfRuntime.WorkflowCompleted -= workflowCompletedHandler;
         }
     };

     _wfRuntime.WorkflowCompleted += workflowCompletedHandler;

     _wfRuntime.GetService<ManualWorkflowSchedulerService>().RunWorkflow(instanceId);
}
```

EDIT: Changed the title of the post to get more views.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you want a "Yes, this code does what you want" (where we should guess what you want from reading the code)?

Comment: The code was previously leaking memory because it was hanging onto the workflow instances in delegates. Something to that effect anyway (it's been quite some time since I've even looked at this).  I was trying to ensure that what I was doing was properly cleaning up after itself.  I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: Is this actually solved now, or do you still search answers? (I don't know anything about the problem, [I'm just trying to clean up badly named questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101923/ive-found-a-particular-set-of-questions-with-bad-titles-how-should-i-proceed/102197#102197).)

Comment: You can close it, I don't care. No one ever responded so I'm not sure if it's 100% correct, but it appears the memory leaks went away, so I guess I didn't screw it up too badly.